# Is there any reason a static variable could not be initialized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static

I have a class (singleton class) that has three global static variables. Each of these static variables has the same type (another class that has a custom init method).

When I want to initialize the static variables, one of them has the value "nil" even if the custom init method returns a valid instance.

Please consider the above code.

```
//The header file of the singleton class

#import "B.h"

static B *firstVariable;
static B *secondVariable;
static B *thirdVariable;

@interface A : NSObject

//some properties and methods declarations here

@end


//The implementation file of the singleton class

#import "A.h"

@implementation A

static A *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (A *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[A alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

...

@end


//The header file for the other class

@interface B : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *path;

- (instancetype)initWithPath:(NSString *)path;

@end

//The implementation of this class

#import "B.h"

@implementation B

- (instancetype)initWithPath:(NSString *)path {
      self = [super init];

      if (self) {
        _path = path;
      }

      return self;
}

@end
```

This is how I try to initialize those static variables

```
firstVariable = [[B alloc] initWithPath:@"firstPath"];
secondVariable = [[B alloc] initWithPath:@"secondPath"];
thirdVariable = [[B alloc] initWithPath:@"thirdPath"];
```

As I previously mentioned, even if there is a valid instance inside of the "initWithPath" method before returning, the "secondVariable" has the "nil" value.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Where are you actually declaring and initialising the instances of B? Can you show it in context?  Also, that isn't the best practice way to create a singleton instance. You should use `dispatch_once`

Comment: Why aren't `firstVariable` etc properties of `A`?

Comment: indeed you should use `dispatch_once`. Because thread safety. Swift uses `dispatch_once` (or something equivalent to `dispatch_once`) internally for global initialization work. You usually define the storage for the singleton (the static var) within `+sharedInstance`.